# Can't access to phpmyadmin error on xampp WINDOWS

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I start apache and mysql today as always do...but when I try to enter to phpmyadmin I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\select_lang.lib.php on line 477

I don't understand what's happening =( ...I did nothing on the folders or config setup PLS HELP !!!

Comment: Save your content from the htdocs and try a reinstall

Comment: Here is an answer http://superuser.com/a/590565

Comment: Im running windows that article is for linux I think

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\ and cut that file select_lang.lib.php ,make sure you paste that item somewhere (if necessary), and phpadmin will run.